# Can't connect to Windows 10 Docker mysql

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

Win 10
Composer version 1.4.1 2017-03-10 09:29:45
PHP 7
npm/Node
Docker CE
Apache 2.4
Powershell
git BASH shell
drush (installed via composer)

Noob Composer/Docker skills

I have a docker config yml specifying how mysql service can start:

```
version: "2"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - /data/nbif_mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
```

And when I call

```
#!/bin/bash
docker-compose up -d mysql
```

I see that the container is running:

```
PS C:\dev\appname> docker ps
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
    f1a0ecab8af6        mysql:5.6           "docker-entrypoint..."   2 hours ago         Up 5 seconds        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   appname_mysql_1
```

But, notice that the reported IP is 0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp

So when I try to connect with the expected IP, it fails:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.17.0.1' (10060)
```

How to I tell docker-compose to use that expected IP for docker?
Is this a setup issue, or some config tweak I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you bind a port to your host, you have to use `localhost` instead of the container's IP address, because you're not assigning any local IP address.

Every container always runs in a isolated network (bridge), the container in your compose file will be able to find the others by their hostname, but *inside* of those containers, they are isolated from the local network so that's why you can't reach them.

In your compose file you only have a `mysql` container and you're binding that port in your host, so the only way to reach that container is by using `localhost:3306`

Remember, when you run a docker container it isn't like a server with an IP in your host network, it's more like a virtual machine with an isolated network configuration.

Take a look on the `docker-compose` docs in this specific topic:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking

UPDATE:

The link that finally answered the question was:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll research this a bit more and update.

Comment: My post asks about why the default IP didn't materialize - is that just attributed to me setting up in Windows? Why is 172.17.0.1 a seemingly common address presented in the Linux resulting environment?

Comment: I doesn't have anything to do with Windows and actually doesn't matter if you're in Windows, Linux or Mac, since the docker containers are linux systems, docker creates its own network interface, take a look in this:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/

Comment: Hey I think that's what I'm looking for - update your answer with that info/link

Comment: It's done, if it's correct you should marked as the answer.